Convert hardwired pendant to plug in
I bought a pendant light that is meant to be hardwired and I would like to convert it to a plug in light ( as I have no existing box in the ceiling). I have read that table lamps are not grounded hence thought may be possible (plus all the youtube "experts" :-O). Plan to use extension cord (lamp cord) for the plug with a surge protector multioutlet box and a remote switch.
The fixture has a socket which is in a plastic/faux wood decorative cover. This hangs from a covered 2 wire (hot & neutral) cord that then is meant to go into the electrical box for ceiling mount. There is a metal cover which goes over the mounting bracket to hide the ceiling box. The shade rests on the faux plastic socket cover and is metal.
The mounting bracket has a ground wire (none in the covered cord with the hot/neutral wires) that is attached to the green (ground) screw on the bracket. This ground wire would then be attached to the ceiling ground wire.
If I do not use the metal ceiling cover and hang the fixture by the cord from the ceiling (using appropriate hangers based on weight which is <6 lbs at most), is a ground necessary? If yes, how would this be added? Or is this fixture simply not appropriate to convert to a plug-in?

If the fixture is all plastic on the outside(where your fingers might touch), ground is kind of useless.  You cannot hang by the electric cord only.

@crip659 some lamps have cords that are designed to be hung from.  Obvs you can't hang it from the plug!
